# jQuery Animate only works one way

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have the following code.

```
$("#social-links a").hover(function()
{
    $(this).children('span').show();
    $(this).children('span').animate({bottom: '25px', opacity: 1}, 300);
}, function()
{
    $(this).children('span').animate({bottom: '0', opacity: 0}, 300);
    $(this).children('span').hide();
});
```

The idea being that the text in the span tag fades in and moves up and then moves down and fades out.  It's working fine for the hover function but when I hover away from the link the animate to fade the span out doesn't seem to work.  It does change the CSS accordingly but it doesn't seem to animate.  Can anyone see if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you setup a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#social-links a").hover(function() {
    $(this).children('span').show().animate({bottom: '25px', opacity: 1}, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).children('span').animate({bottom: '0', opacity: 0}, 300).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call hide after the animation is complete:

```
 $(this).children('span').animate({bottom: '0', opacity: 0}, 300, function(){
     $(this).hide();
 });
```

Or, using deferred objects:

```
var $el = $(this).children('span');
$.when($el.animate({bottom: '0', opacity: 0}, 300)).then(function(){
    $el.hide();
})
```

At the moment your code starts the animation and then immediately hides the div, because the effect of `.hide` is immediate, rather than it being added to the animation queue.

Comment: +1, yes the `.hide()` is instantly making it `display:none;` so the animation goes unnoticed.

Comment: Ah yes! I knew it was something simple.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Apply a callback function when animation is completed. More on [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$(this).children('span').animate({bottom: '0', opacity: 0}, 300, function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```